# Laptop and 4K Monitor Compatibility

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 4k-resolution

I have an [Asus VivoBook 15 X510UR-BQ166T](https://www.submarino.com.br/produto/132532981/notebook-asus-vivobook-x510ur-bq166t-intel-core-i5-8gb-geforce-930mx-de-2gb-1tb-tela-fhd-nano-edge-15-6-windows-10-cinza-mesclado?WT.srch=1&epar=bp_pl_00_go_pla_inf_geral_1p&fbclid=IwAR03t_4BUMFOSoz-MQsgPNv8b2HMaqoXIPXs80BdM6Cjf26ooRExF12WgBw&gclid=CjwKCAiA_c7UBRAjEiwApCZi8e4nGhVej4B2jV7jF1QUmGvxeACr5_ZuQH3RqaVHqpeFfxldA7hPlxoCMMUQAvD_BwE&opn=XMLGOOGLE) (Intel Core i5-7200U 2.50GHz, NVIDIA GeForce 930MX 2GB GDDR5, RAM DDR4 8GB, USB 3.1 Type-C, HDMI) and recently bought a [LG 32UD59-B](https://www.lg.com/br/monitores/lg-32UD59-B-monitor-32-lg-resolucao-uhd-4k-amd-freesync) (31.5" UHD 4K, AMD FreeSync, DisplayPort, HDMI 4k), which I'm still waiting to be delivered.

Immediately after buying it I was quite concerned about a question: is it possible to use the monitor in 4K resolution and 60Hz without a DisplayPort? I couldn't find the HDMI version supported and I don't know if USB Type-C could stream in 4k. I chose this monitor precisely because of its image quality, response time, pixel density, size and resolution, and I may have had a terrible deal if I can't use it with my laptop.

I don't plan on playing hard games or using modeling programs, I just wish I could read, code and watch movies without seeing pixels or waiting for the mouse to move, which pisses me off a lot.

If my fear is real and I can't really connect it directly, is there any kind of passive/active converter/adapter or dock station that I could use to get the most out of the resolution? I don't understand how this would be possible since the limitation should be the laptop's connector output speed, but I've seen some people comment on this and I was quite confused.

Does there seem to be any workable solution or should I start thinking about returning the monitor before the company actually delivers it? Here in my country this kind of hardware is very expensive, and exchanging products is always a complicated issue, which is why I am concerned.

Comment: If your USB port supports display output, your USB C port is DisplayPort, just with a different connector. It can stream the same things DisplayPort can, becuse it is the same. However, not all USB C ports can be used as a display output (unless you use some kind of USB graphics card in between).

Comment: Thanks @Peter! How can I find if my USB C port can be used as a display output? And what do you mean by some kind of USB graphics card in between?

Answer (score 0):

So I've done some research and your monitor supports hdmi 2.0 and display port 1.2, both of these can play 4k @60hz, I could not find out what type of hdmi your VivoBook is so not sure on that but anything 1.4 or later should do 4k. As for the usb-type C, the VivoBook is 3.1 gen 1 where as in order to get a display output you need a usb thunderbolt 3, so while a type c to display port would fit in your VivoBook it will not give out a display. I will continue to look for the type of hdmi on the vivo and let you know if i find out but for now the only way you can connect to the monitor is using that hdmi port.

Comment: Note that for HDMI, v1.4 will support 4:2:0, 2.0 and higher will support any.  You will need a cable rated Premium for 4K60 HDR (or basically any content requiring HDMI 2.0 bandwidth).  For 4K60 SDR, you can probably get by with a cable rated High Speed.  But if you need to buy a cable and the VivoBook supports HDMI 2.0, it might be worth just getting a Premium one to avoid needing to upgrade later since the monitor supports 2.0.